# ifstream tellg() not returning the correct position

Tags: c++, file, fstream

#### read.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int id;
    char name[50];
    ifstream myfile("savingaccount.txt");  //open the file
    myfile >> id;
    cout << myfile.tellg(); //return 16? but not 7 or 8
    cout << id ;

    return 0;
}
```

#### savingaccount.txt

```
1800567
Ho Rui Jang
21
Female
Malaysian
012-4998192
20 , Lorong 13 , Taman Patani Janam
Melaka
Sungai Dulong
```

#### The Problem

I expect the `tellg()` to either return `7` or `8` since the first line `1800567` which is 7 digits so the stream pointer should be placed after this number and before the string `"Ho Rui Jang"`, but `tellg()` returns `16`. Why is it so?

Comment: Is the file saved with a special encoding? with ANSI encoding it seems to work fine (reports 7) on Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Actually the data inside the file was written using ofstream , the problem only exist when I use ofstream to write data and again the above code will return wrong tellg() position.It won't happen when the file is handwritten(type using keyboard)

Comment: Would you mind adding the function/method that writes to the file? if it works when the file is typed then it's probably a padding issue or something like that.

Comment: On windows with file opened in text mode, seeking and position operations are buggy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems more like a compiler bug (probably gcc)

With the following Code:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    int id;
    char name[50];
    ifstream myfile("savingaccount.txt");  //open the file
    cout << myfile.tellg()<<endl;
    myfile >> id;
    streamoff pos=myfile.tellg();
    cout <<"pos= "<<pos<<'\n';
    cout <<"id= " << id<<'\n' ;
    return 0;
}
```

Following is the output:-

[image: Bug]

In the image `inpstr.exe` was generated from `Visual studio's cl` while `inp.exe` from `g++(gcc version 4.6.1 (tdm-1))`

Comment: Perhaps a bug should be raised, and lets see what they respond.

Comment: I'm here sitting for the past 5-6 hours try to figure out the problem . I appear to be a very persistent type and i'm so focus in solving the problem till I didnt think of asking it at here until I get up to get myself a cup of milk . Now the problem is causes by the gcc bug

Comment: I have learnt in my life...Never believe one thing, till you think you are right :)

Comment: @caramel23 Are you on Windows? I was able to reproduce this on Windows with GCC 4.7.0 but not on Ubuntu with GCC 4.6.3. This might be a Windows-specific bug.

Comment: Persistence is like a disease , infected me whenever problem comes and I will be so focus on solving the problem until I forget I could consult someone . Now I'm regret for wasting my time messing around with this bug

Comment: I see this issue with VS2015. Wouldn't be surprising if it's a windows bug.

Comment: I see this issue under Windows 7, using MINGW GCC 5.3.0 32-bit but not under MSVC 2015 64-bit.

Answer (score 10):

had the same issue. try to read the filestream binary:

```
    ifstream myfile("savingaccount.txt",ios::binary);
```

it helped for me

Comment: It did for me too. I think that if the file is UTF-8 without setting binary flag, ifstream load a "é" as only one character, whereas it takes two.

Comment: This answer is especially useful if you are on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

It is not a compiler bug.  `tellg()` is not guaranteed to return an offset from the start of the file.   There are a minimal set of guarantees such as, if the return value from `tellg()` is passed to `seekg()`, the file pointer will position at the corresponding point in the file.

In practice, under unix, `tellg()` does return an offset from the start of the file.   Under windows, it returns an offset from the beginning of the file but only if the file is opened in binary mode.

But the only real guarantee is that different values returned from `tellg()` will correspond to different positions in the file.

Comment: When I save a pos with tellg() and set it again with seekg(), it goes to another position slightly later in the file. (win7 mingw gcc 5.3.0).